# How to get rid of dragging-ghost pointer?

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, windows-update, ghost

Outlook email ghost pointer and drags from main pointer, using mouse. Also, pointer will not move emails from inbox to archive. Seemed to happen after an update to W-10 OS.

Answer (score 0):

It wounds like actually this doesn't have anything to do with outlook, but rather a graphics display issue or a touchpad driver issue.

I would suggest to update your graphics drivers for your computer to the latest version, and also make sure your touchpad drivers are up to date if you are using a touchpad.

Let me know if this fixes it, if not I will update if you give me new information.

Answer (score 0):

Search Mouse options in the start menu, go to additional mouse options and select pointer options. Then uncheck Display pointer trails in visibility.